# Problem with delimiter of double click in Mobaxterm

Tags: delimiter, double-click, mobaxterm

The delimiter of double click is not working when performed in the path.
When I use the double click to select the path, it stops only in the @. As example below:

user@server:/home/user

The answer of the double click in server is: server

The answer of the double click in home is: server:/home/user

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In old versions of MobaXterm (for instance Personal Edition v10.6), the issue really happens when you double click in any text. It does not treat left colons ":" as delimiters. However, right colons are treated as delimiters.

Example:
Consider that the string being displayed in the current moba prompt is:
"user@server:/home/user#"

- When you double click over "home", moba selects "server:/home/user" <<<--- so it is not treating left colon as delimiter.
- When you double click over "server", moba selects "server" <<<--- treating  the right colon as delimiter.

---

However in new versions the issue is fixed:
Tested successfully on MobaXterm Personal Edition v20.6